# matplotlib, combine 2 individual axes and then, plot data

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, plot

I'd like to create **individual** axes, and then, choose 2 of them to plot data. For example :

```
x_axis = XAxis(fig, position=(0.2, 0.1), length=0.7)
y_axis = YAxis(fig, position=(0.1, 0.2), length=0.7)
plot_within_axes(fig, x_axis, y_axis, np.random.random_sample(5))
```

[image: Click here to view the expected result].

Here is my implementation, and of course, I'm not happy with it :

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class XAxis:
    def __init__(self, figure, position, length):
        self.position = position
        self.length = length
        axes = figure.add_axes([position[0], position[1], length, 0.1])
        axes.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
        axes.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
        axes.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
        axes.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
        axes.set_yticks([])
        axes.patch.set_alpha(0)
        self.axes = axes

class YAxis:
    def __init__(self, figure, position, length): 
        self.position = position
        self.length = length
        axes = fig.add_axes([position[0], position[1], 0.1, length])
        axes.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
        axes.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
        axes.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
        axes.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
        axes.set_xticks([])
        axes.patch.set_alpha(0)
        self.axes = axes

def plot_within_axes(figure, x_axis, y_axis, values):
    axes = fig.add_axes([x_axis.position[0], y_axis.position[1], x_axis.length, y_axis.length])
    x_limits = x_axis.axes.get_xlim()
    axes.plot(np.linspace(x_limits[0], x_limits[1], len(values), endpoint=True), values)
    axes.set_ylim(y_axis.axes.get_ylim())
    axes.set_xticks([])
    axes.set_yticks([])
    axes.patch.set_alpha(0)

fig = plt.figure()
x_axis = XAxis(fig, position=(0.2, 0.1), length=0.7)
y_axis = YAxis(fig, position=(0.1, 0.2), length=0.7)
plot_within_axes(fig, x_axis, y_axis, np.random.random_sample(5))
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')

plt.show()
```

(I used 2 plotting areas to draw 2 axes, I hid unwanted spines, unwanted ticks, unwanted background, I used a 3rd plotting area to draw my data, it's a very ugly trick)

I don't know if it's possible to handle **individual** axes with matplotlib. For me, an axis is a straight line, but for matplotlib, it makes no sense to draw an **individual** axis.

Is it possible to do it with matplotlib low-level primitives ?

My final objective is to create an application to handle axes, draw them anywhere at any (x,y) position, without any ugly trick, and of course, plot graphs within those axes.